# Fast kernel recompile

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel, makefile, incremental-build

I'm trying to automate the process of recompile a upgraded kernel. (I mean version upgrade)

What I do:

1. Backup the object files (*.o) with rsync
2. Remove the directory and make mrproper
3. Extract new source and patch
4. Restore object files with rsync

But I found it doesn't make sense. Since skip compiled things need to get a hash, this should removed it.

Question: What file do I need to keep? or it doesn't exists?

BTW: I already know ccache but it broke with a little config change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incremental patch is a good way since it updates time stamps properly.

(GNU) Make use time stamps to identify rebuild so just keep the time stamps to avoid rebuild.

If we need rsync, we should use it with -t option.

Also for a patch doesn't have incremental patches, we can make it manually by comparing patched files.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong™ :-)

Keep the kernel tree as-is and simply patch it using the appropriate incremental patch. For example, for 3.x, you find these patches here:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/incr/

If you currently have 3.18.11 built and want to upgrade to 3.18.12, download the 3.18.11-12 patch:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/incr/patch-3.18.11-12.xz

(or the .gz file, if you don't have the xz utilities installed.)

and apply it. Then "make oldconfig" and "make". Whatever needs to be rebuilt will be rebuilt.

However, it's actually best to not rely on the object file dependency mechanism. Who knows if something might end up not being rebuilt even though it should due to a bug. So I'd recommend starting clean every time with a "make clean" before applying the patch, even though it will rebuild everything.

Are you really in such a big need to save build time? If yes, it might be a better idea to configure the kernel ("make menuconfig") and disable all functionality you don't need (like device drivers for hardware you don't have, file systems you don't care about, networking features you will not use, etc.) Such a kernel that's optimized for my needs only takes about 3 or 4 minutes to build (normally, the full kernel with everything enabled would need over half an hour; or even more these days, it's been a very long time since I've built non-optimized kernels.)

Some more info on kernel patches:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/applying-patches.txt

Comment: First, please answer detail about kernel's file hash/dependency system. Also, my custom patch also needs to update and it doesn't provide incremental things.